# ggplot2 how do I change chart from ggplot2 data to my own data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I successfully created small multiple radar charts using the 'msleep' ggplot2 package, as below.

[image: msleep radar charts]

But when I load my own dataset and try to plot using my own data, I keep getting the following error:

> Error in select(country, democracy, freedom, corruption) :
>    object 'country' not found

Here is the original code:

```
# prepare data
data(msleep, package = "ggplot2")
library(ggradar)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

plotdata <- msleep %>%
  filter(name %in% c("Cow", "Dog", "Pig")) %>%
  select(name, sleep_total, sleep_rem, 
         sleep_cycle, brainwt, bodywt) %>%
  rename(group = name) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group),
            funs(rescale))
plotdata

# generate radar chart
ggradar(plotdata, 
        grid.label.size = 4,
        axis.label.size = 4, 
        group.point.size = 5,
        group.line.width = 1.5,
        legend.text.size= 10) +
  labs(title = "Mammals, size, and sleep")
```

And here is my code that's throwing me the error:

```
# prepare data
library(ggradar)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

radarData <- read.csv(file="Index_Data - radar-chart-wide (2).csv")

radarData
  select(country, democracy, freedom, corruption) %>%
  rename(country = groups) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-country),
            funs(rescale))
  radarData
```

And here's a screenshot of what my data looks like:

[image: personal data]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: first of all, there seems to be a `%>%` missing, just before `select(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with the `rename` call. It follows the syntax

```
rename(new_name = old_name)
```

but you used it the other way around.

Anyway, since you refer to column `country` in the `mutate_at` statement after that, you probably want to keep the name as it is. So you can omit the call to `rename`:

```
df <- radarData %>% 
  select(country, democracy, freedom, corruption) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-country),
            funs(rescale))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I got it working and shortened the data for easiness...

Here's the code:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar")

# prepare data
library(ggradar)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

radarDataShort <- read.csv(file="Index_Data - radar-chart-wide2 (1).csv")

dfShort <- radarDataShort %>%
  select(country, democracy, freedom, corruption) %>%
  #mutate_at(vars(),
  mutate_at(vars(-country),
            funs(rescale))
dfShort

# generate radar chart
ggradar(dfShort, 
        grid.label.size = 4,
        axis.label.size = 4, 
        group.point.size = 0,
        group.line.width = 1)
```

[radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLKYy.png)

However, when I try to facet_wrap, I get the following error:

> Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables:
>   `country`.
>       * Plot is missing `country`
>       * Layer 1 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 2 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 3 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 4 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 5 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 6 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 7 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 8 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 9 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 10 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 11 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 12 is missing `country`
>       * Layer 13 is missing `country`

And here's my latest code w/ the facet_wrap

```
# prepare data
library(ggradar)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

radarDataShort <- read.csv(file="Index_Data - radar-chart-wide2 (1).csv")

dfShort <- radarDataShort %>%
  select(country, democracy, freedom, corruption) %>%
  #mutate_at(vars(),
  mutate_at(vars(-country),
            funs(rescale))
dfShort

# generate radar chart
ggradar(dfShort, 
        grid.label.size = 4,
        axis.label.size = 4, 
        group.point.size = 0,
        group.line.width = 1) +
facet_wrap(~country)
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason, the facet_wrap required (~group) and NOT (~country). Not sure why, as group is not included in my data. Perhaps it's a generic function in ggradar?

Thank you anyway!